# I hava installed requests moudel ,but i can't use it

Tags: python

I have installed both python 2.6.9 && python 3.4.3 && python 2.7.6; and I have installed requests moudel in python2.7/sitepacakges folder.However,when I use 'import requests', PyCharm show--"no moudel named requests".Why? 
  And how can I delete python 2.6.9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way with pycharm is the folowing:

Go to your settings > project.

choose your interpreter  (python version) and then prees the '+' button to add modules.

see this screenshoot: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34827065/add%20module.jpg

Hope this help.